# ¿Cómo saber si una lista contiene al menos un elemento de otra lista?

Tags: android, lista, kotlin, filtro, collection

Tengo una clase Recetas que tiene una `List<String> listaIngredientes`.
Por otro lado, tengo una `List<String> ingredientes`. Quiero filtrar la lista de Recetas con sólo las recetas que contenga al menos un item de la lista **ingredientes**.
Intento lo siguiente:

```
val ingredientes: List<String> = user.getIngredientes()
val listaFiltrada = listaRecetas.filter {it.listaIngredientes.containsAll(ingredientes)}
```

Pero el error aquí es que containsAll me filtra si todos los ingredientes están en la lista **listaIngredientes** y yo solo quiero que al menos exista un ingrediente.

Si hago lo mismo con:

```
val ingredientes: List<String> = user.getIngredientes()
val listaFiltrada = listaRecetas.filter {it.listaIngredientes.contains()}
```

No puedo pasar la lista ingredientes porque me pide un sólo elemento (String).
Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opción más eficiente es usar la función [any](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#test-predicates) que sirve para verificar si una lista (o cualquier objeto iterable) contiene al menos un elemento que cumpla cierta condición. En tu caso la condición sería que el elemento exista en la otra lista:

```
val listaFiltrada = listaRecetas.filter { receta ->
    receta.listaIngredientes.any { it in ingredientes }
}
```

que tambíen se puede escribir así

```
receta.listaIngredientes.any { ingredientes.contains(it) }
```

o así

```
receta.listaIngredientes.any(ingredientes::contains)
```

Si esperas que la lista `ingredientes` tenga más elementos que `receta.listaIngredientes`, sería más eficiente invertir el orden

```
val listaFiltrada = listaRecetas.filter { ingredientes.any(it.listaIngredientes::contains) }
```

Otra opción puede ser usar la función [intersect](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) para buscar los elementos en común y luego verificar si es mayor a `0`

```
val listaFiltrada = listaRecetas.filter {
    it.listaIngredientes.intersect(ingredientes).isNotEmpty()
}
```

pero esto siempre será más lento porque necesita recorrer completamente la lista. En cambio `any()` termina el bucle al encontrar el primer elemento que satisfaga la condición.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió!!